# WCF stream to Android

Tags: android, .net, wcf, rest, stream

I've got a WCF RESTful service that when hit returns an obscene amount of data. This RESTful service is specifically designed to be hit by Android (and iOS eventually). Does anyone have any ideas of the best way to implement a WCF service that returns a stream and an Android client that downloads it in the background?

-edit
I should note that I am already using AsyncTask, but I want to know if there is anything additional I need to have it download a stream.

Answer (score 0):

Rest is platform agnostic so it does not matter. You should look into [WCF 4: Download Files using WCF REST EndPoints](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to deal with downloading the heavy stuff in the back.

Comment: I'm already using AsyncTask, I just want to know how to have WCF send a stream and have Android download the stream. As it is now, it all comes over in one big httpresponse. Can I have it come over in multiple packets?

Comment: then what do you need? you have WCF service and you have async task.

Comment: as it is right now, WCF is sending a giant xml file and AsyncTask is receiving it in one big httpresponse message

Comment: I think, it is fine. how big is the xml ? Iirc, you have to go with xml if you want to do it for iOS since iOS does not have json support or something like that I heard last time. Otherwise, going with json can reduce the footprint. json for android and xml for iOS? maybe too much workload ?

Comment: Not necessarily, my first reaction was to use json but I wasn't aware that iOS didn't support it. The xml, in theory, has the potential of being arbitrarily large. This is why I want to use a stream, I'd like to have the phone download and then use a handler to add things to a listactivity as they are downloaded. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: if it is very large, how about chunk it? sort of pagination, you know.

Comment: Yes, I think this is essentially what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure how to chunk it with WCF or how to read the chunks with Android.